# Need help in understanding the part of Single Variable Calculus lecture

Tags: calculus

I do not understand the following from [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_JXPe2J069c) video at 2:28:

I just don't make sense of what is happening. Why do we have definite integral from $1$ to $x$?
[image]

Thanks

Comment: I'm pretty sure the definite integral is used because the indefinite integral would produce a $+C$ which you don't want. The top bound will give you essentially what you get from the anti derivative (you just plug in x instead of t) and the bottom bound was chosen to be 1 because $\ln (1) = 0$ so we don't have a constant.

Comment: By the Fundamental theorem of calculus, $L'(x) = 1/x$. In defining $L(x)$ the constant $1$ can be replaced by  another constant such as $2$, but $1$ is convenient since then the resulting function is the natural log (although this is far from obvious, unless you define the natural logarithm function this way, which is sometimes done).

Answer (score 2):

It is just a definition,

$$
\ln x = \int_1^x\frac{{\rm d }t}{t}
$$

With this, you can check that it satisfies all properties you may know

1. $d \ln x/dx = 1/x$

$$
\frac{{\rm d}\ln x}{{\rm d}x} = \frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}x} \int_1^x\frac{{\rm d }t}{t} = \frac{1}{x}
$$

2. $\ln 1 = 0$

   $$
    \ln 1 = \int_1^1\frac{{\rm d }t}{t} = 0
    $$
3. $\ln(xy) = \ln x + \ln y$

   \begin{eqnarray}
   \ln (xy) &=& \int_1^{xy}\frac{{\rm d }t}{t} = \int_1^{x}\frac{{\rm d }t}{t} + \int_x^{xy}\frac{{\rm d }t}{t} \\
   &=& \int_1^{x}\frac{{\rm d }t}{t} + \int_x^{xy}\frac{{\rm d }(t/x)}{(t/x)} \\
   &\stackrel{u=t/x}{=}& \int_1^{x}\frac{{\rm d }t}{t} + \int_1^{y}\frac{{\rm d }u}{u} = \ln x + \ln y
   \end{eqnarray}
4. ($\cdots$)

Comment: what about 0 < x < 1 ?

Comment: @YohanRoth Do you mean, why isn't defined as $\int_0^x{\rm d t}/t$?

Comment: Yes, what happens for values of x < 1

Comment: Plot the function $f(t) = 1/t$ and see what happens near zero. That's the problem.

Comment: @YohanRoth You should avoid using 0 as the lower limit, because it makes the integral diverge. If you pick another number $0<b \not= 1$ instead, and call the resulting function $\ln_b x$ the first property is not changed, that is $d\ln_b x/dx = 1$, however the second one breaks $\ln_b 1 \not = 0$, and that is in general a good thing to have. Remember that you could interpret $\ln 1$ as the number you have to power $e$ to get 1, which is zero. $\ln_b 1 \not = 0$ so, this interpretation fails